# Visual Studio 2015 appears to complie VB code with C#

Tags: visual-studio, vs-extensibility

```
Steps to Reproduce:
Create new Visual Basic Analyzer with Code Fix (NuGet + VSIX)
From VSIX project add New Item...
Extensibility/Custom Command called "CustomCommand"
Not required but helps see the issue set the following options
    Option Explicit Off
    Option Strict Off
    Option Infer On
Build Solution
```

Several files are added and you get 381 warnings for the ComandComand.vb and CustomCommandPackage.vb files. The warnings are "Type or namespace definition or end-of-line expected", "Newline in Comment", "Type Expected" , "Too many characters in character literal"., "Comma Expected". None of which make any sense in a VB file. If I included these files in a C# project and rename them to .cs I get the exact same errors. The errors make no sense for a .VB file.

Answer (score 0):

The example above is complete and shows a bug in Visual Studio 2015. In the VSIX project file there are two lines that include the word "CSharp" that must be changed to "VisualBasic" otherwise the VB code will be compiled by the C# compiler. To edit the file, unload the VSIX project from within Visual Studio, replace occurrences of "CSharp" with "VisualBasic", Save and reopen the solution the 381 Errors/Warning will go away.